# Why was my comment deleted?

Tags: discussion, comments

Last night I made a comment on a post about dealing with rude drivers. I recounted a story in which a carload of obese women yelled "Get the f*k off the road!" at me. I caught up to them at the next stop sign and said as I was rolling past them, "Maybe if you got out here on the road with me you wouldn't be the fat cows you are."

Why would a mod delete that comment? I can no longer see the comment to make sure I didn't spell out the vulgarity, but I'm pretty sure I wouldn't have. So it violated no rules I can find, and there is no shortage of other non-constructive comments out there that don't get deleted. While I suppose I could be criticized for being rude to the motorists, I most certainly wasn't rude to anyone here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your comment did, in fact, have the f-bomb fully spelled out. However, it was not deleted by a moderator.

Comments with vulgar words are auto deleted as soon as they receive a single flag to comply with the network wide [behavior policy](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice). You can read more about it in [this meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121225/flagged-comments-disappear-instantly-whats-going-on/121226#121226).

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks for the explanation and I'm surprised I spelled it out. Stupid oversight on my part since even if SE didn't auto-delete such things, many people's employers or family filters might block the content.

Comment: I saw your comment, and while I would normally object, I thought it was appropriate at the time. Interesting to learn about the auto-delete.